# SQL query it works great but I need a select all to work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with my SQL query. Be gentle I am new to SQL and database work.

here are my parameters
Parameter 1=start time, parameter 2=end time, parameter 3= station name

here is my query.

```
SELECT Paintline_Estops.Stationname,
  Paintline_Estops.Duration,
  Paintline_Estops.[Time]
FROM Paintline_Estops
WHERE Paintline_Estops.Duration > 0 and
Paintline_Estops.[Time] BETWEEN ? AND ? and
Paintline_Estops.Stationname = ?
ORDER BY Paintline_Estops.[Time] DESC
```

Now this query works perfectly, but the problem is I need a way to select everything.

I have the station name being selected from a dropdown menu, but I have select all in the dropdown and I can not get this to work.

basically to select all I could write this

```
select *
from Paintline_Estops
WHERE Paintline_Estops.Duration > 0 and
Paintline_Estops.[Time] BETWEEN ? AND ? and
ORDER BY Paintline_Estops.[Time] DESC
```

I need to find a way to combine these two scripts.

another way I tried to pull all the stations is this(by adding a ! in-front of my third ?). This pulls all the data I need for select all but I do not know how to have this only work select all is selected in the dropdown menu.

```
SELECT Paintline_Estops.Stationname,
  Paintline_Estops.Duration,
  Paintline_Estops.[Time]
FROM Paintline_Estops
WHERE Paintline_Estops.Duration > 0 and
Paintline_Estops.[Time] BETWEEN ? AND ? and
Paintline_Estops.Stationname = !?
ORDER BY Paintline_Estops.[Time] DESC
```

I feel like this is a common thing to do. to have a dropdown menu with a select all.

Comment: This isn't MySQL. What SQL dialect are you actually using?

Comment: It sounds like you need two different queries but honestly I don't understand your question. [Sample data and desired output would help greatly here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble not with the query itself, but entering the query through whatever query builder you're using. I mean, you don't have a question of what SQL you need, but rather how to get it into the program you're using. So what program is it? Also, most allow you to type a query in directly instead of using the builder, so try taking your "good query" and editing it to replace the 3 field names in the SELECT with just a *. Post back to let us know if you get it.

Comment: Please check the answers below and rate the one that took you to the solution, or provide some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

One common way to accomplish this task is when you click "Select All" on your UI, then you will send a general value in your parameter to SQL. It could be something like "ALL" or -1. For this particular case, we are using "ALL".

```
DECLARE
     @FromDate DATE
    ,@ToDate DATE
    ,@StationName VARCHAR(150) -- If you select all on UI, them you send here 'ALL'

SELECT [Stationname], [Duration], [Time]
FROM [Paintline_Estops]
WHERE [Duration] > 0
    AND [Time] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    AND (@StationName = 'ALL' OR [Stationname] = @StationName)
ORDER BY [Time] DESC
```

Hopefully, this will get you where you need to - Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, that's what you are looking for:

```sql
select *, EXISTS(
    SELECT id
    FROM Paintline_Estops
    WHERE Paintline_Estops.Duration > 0 and
    Paintline_Estops.[Time] BETWEEN ? AND ? and
    Paintline_Estops.Stationname = ?
    ORDER BY Paintline_Estops.[Time] DESC
) AS is_selected
from Paintline_Estops
WHERE Paintline_Estops.Duration > 0 and
Paintline_Estops.[Time] BETWEEN ? AND ? and
ORDER BY Paintline_Estops.[Time] DESC
```

With this you can build a dropdown like this (this is just pseudo code!):

```html
<select>
    <option <%= option.is_selected ? 'selected' : '' %>><%= option.Stationname %></option>
</select>
```

But it would be easier to do these queries separately and just check for the estop's id (this is just pseudo code!):

```
allEstops = query('
    select *
    from Paintline_Estops
    WHERE Paintline_Estops.Duration > 0 and
    Paintline_Estops.[Time] BETWEEN ? AND ? and
    ORDER BY Paintline_Estops.[Time] DESC
')
getStationQuery = query('
    SELECT id
    FROM Paintline_Estops
    WHERE Paintline_Estops.Duration > 0 and
    Paintline_Estops.[Time] BETWEEN ? AND ? and
    Paintline_Estops.Stationname = ?
    ORDER BY Paintline_Estops.[Time] DESC
')

<select>
    /* foreach allEstops as option */
    <option <%= getStationQuery.id === option.id ? 'selected' : '' %>><%= option.Stationname %></option>
</select>
```